# RadiusNetworks iBeacon virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, ibeacon

Has anyone tried RadiusNetworks iBeacon virtual machine? When I am asked to fill in the login and password I use the ones that are used to access their developers area, but it says the password is wrong.

When running the virtual machine for the first time there was a prompt warning about a wifi interface problem... may it be the cause of this? Or am I just writing a wrong user/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion.  I work for Radius Networks, and use the iBeacon Virtual Machine regularly.  Here is a link to some more detailed instructions:

https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service/wiki/Virtual-iBeacon

I would need to see the exact wording of the "wifi interface problem" you mention.  But the virtual machine has no need for a WiFi connection (it just needs a Bluetooth LE dongle.)  So the warning may be harmless.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I read the documentation and I realized I was using the wrong login and password. I am thinking of doing my end of degree project with bluetooth low energy technology and Android, so I need a virtual iBeacon. Any guidance about What steps should I take next or where can I get more info about how to program the iBeacon to send the data I want (e.g. GPS coordinates)?

Comment: IBeacons do not send any data other than their identifiers.  If you want to get additional data about an iBeacon (like its geographic coordinates), you must put that info in a lookup table either embedded in your mobile app or hosted by a web service.  You then write code in your app that gets the identifier for the iBeacon, then does the lookup to get the coordinates.

Comment: Oh! then my intuition on how the iBeacons work was completely wrong! Thank you for the explanation :)